# Фильтрация записей по дате django

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-model

Подскажите, пожалуйста, не могу разобраться, ответа не нашел. Есть 2 модели:

```py
class Datadate(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField('Date', unique=True)
class Data(models.Model):
    date_id = models.ForeignKey(Datadate, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='dates')
    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=60, default='Empty')
    hours = models.FloatField('Hours', default=0)
```

Мне необходимо выводить записи таблицы `Data` сгруппированными по дате (например:

`01.01.2023 - title1 1час, title2 1час`,

`02.01.2023 - title3 2часа, title4 3часа`)

Через annotate получилось вывести только количество записей за дату

```py
date_set = Datadate.objects.annotate(num_dates=Count('dates'))
```

```
{% for e in date_set %}
    {{e.num_dates}}
{% endfor %}
```

но мне нужно выводить `title` и `hours`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать? Если можно все в одной модели, то переделаю на одну

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подход с двумя моделями вполне адекватный, давайте с ним и работать. Плюс разберем пару конфузов.

`related_name` - в соответствии [с документацией](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) - название, которое будет использоваться для ***возврата*** от указанного объекта к текущему. По умолчанию джанго [сам создает](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) это имя менеджера у связанного объекта, используя шаблон foo_set, где foo - название модели (lowercase).

Таким образом, у вас, если бы не было указано `related_name`, доступ ко всем связанным `Data` через `Datadate` был бы:

```
last_dd = Datadate.objects.last()
last_dd.data_set.all() # здесь data_set - такой же менеджер, как objects
```

Тут мы понимаем, что для обратной связи от даты к данным мы задали путающее имя `dates` - то есть сейчас для доступа к связанным `Data` через `Datadate` мы бы использовали

```
last_dd.dates.all()
```

Но мы уже вполне можем выводить записи таблицы Data сгруппированными по дате:

```
date_set = Datadate.objects.prefetch_related('dates').all()
```

(ссылка на [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related))
и в шаблоне

```
{% for e in date_set %}
    {{e.date}} - {% for data in e.dates.all %}{{data.title}} {{data.hours }},{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Запятые можно контролировать с помощью [`forloop`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for).

Рекомендации, не относящиеся к вопросу:

- переименуйте `related_name`. Можно вообще его убрать, чтобы пользоваться `data_set` по умолчанию, а можно назвать так, чтобы было понятно, что менеджер ведет *от даты к данным*. (не забудьте про миграции)
- `date_id` лучше тоже переименовать - убрать _id. По умолчанию это свойство будет возвращать сам объект `Datadate`, а не него ID. Если оставить, сам id надо будет получать с помощью `date_id_id`. Подробнее про queryset и как в нем работают поля *_id тоже есть [в доках](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#database-representation). (снова миграции)

У джанго очень крутой ORM, с большим количеством возможностей и документации.
Я постоянно обращаюсь к следующим страницам доков, посмтрите их, там есть много полезного:

[Model field reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/)

[QuerySet API reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/)

[Built-in template tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/)

Comment: Огромное спасибо, выполнил все рекомендации, все работает как нужно. Буду изучать документацию, еще раз спасибо!